# newby needs guidance with what is probably a simple function

Tags: python

I'm struggling to write a function to pass the following doctests. I can't find a way to make the third argument in the parameter optional:

write whole function definition for make_numberlist including the
function header and body so the doctests pass

```
def make_numberlist():
"""
Return a list of the numbers from first to last exclusive with an
optional step.
>>> make_numberlist(3,9,2)
[3, 5, 7]
>>> make_numberlist(-3,2)
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
>>> make_numberlist(5,1,-1)
[5, 4, 3, 2]
"""
return range (r1, r2, step)
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to give your function arguments:

```
def make_numberlist(r1, r2, step=1):
    return range(r1, r2, step)
```

`r1` and `r2` are required arguments, but `step` is optional and has a default value of `1`.

You could also just do:

```
make_numberlist = range
```

If you're using Python 3 (which you probably are), `range` doesn't return a list, so I would take that into consideration.